# How can i force Display names to be the same as Usernames?

Tags: plugins, custom-field, users, user-registration, username

i need help. My users register to the website. They type their username **user_login** (see chello)  but the Display name (see chello04) is not the same. It has a random two digits at the end.

Is there a way to force Display names to be the same as usernames?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`wp_pre_insert_user_data`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_pre_insert_user_data/) filter.

```
function wpse_filter_user_data( $data, $update, $id) {
  if( isset( $data[ 'user_login' ] ) ) {
    $data[ 'display_name' ] = $data[ 'user_login' ];
    return $data;
  }
  $user = get_user_by( 'email', $data[ 'user_email' ] );
  $data[ 'display_name' ] = $user->user_login;
  return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_pre_insert_user_data', 'wpse_filter_user_data', 10, 3 );
```

You'll probably want to use Javascript and/or CSS to hide the field too for a better user experience.

```
$( '.user-display-name-wrap' ).remove();

.user-display-name-wrap {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful support here on this debate and I would like to know the same function but 'Display name publicly as' to be the First + Last names please. Thanks, Andy

Answer (score 0):

I would do with jQuery:

```
add_action('admin_footer','myPlugin_fixed_user_name');

function myPlugin_fixed_user_name(){
  ob_start();
  ?>
  <script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    if( pagenow == 'profile' || pagenow == 'user-edit' ){// up to you decide wether to run on edit user ( made by admin ) also or only on personal profile 
      var uName=$('#user_login').val();
      $('#display_name option[text="'+uName+'"]').attr('selected','selected');
      $('#display_name').attr('disabled',true);
    }
  })
  </script>
  <?php
  echo ob_get_clean();
  }

//To be 100% safe you can also run a function on user profile update:

add_action('personal_options_update', 'my_update_extra_profile_fields');

function my_update_extra_profile_fields($user_id) {
  if ( current_user_can('edit_user',$user_id) )
     wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'display_name' => $_POST['user_login'] ) );
}
```

Comment: I would rather do that with a simple plugin or with a php code in functions.php

Comment: you can just add this code in functions.php or in a plugin..it's written to be used that ways of course

Comment: I've edited, take the whole code block and use it in functions.php or in your plugin

Comment: Should this code change the existing users' Display names as usernames? Or it will only affect the newly registered users?

Comment: Because when i edit user it just locked the chello04 (if you look at my question's figure)

Comment: this avoid that a user can change it and upon update it will be always saved as the login name, but  for the old ones, you should enter the edit screen and save them again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81504/discussion-between-andrea-somovigo-and-csandreas1).

Comment: why downvote please?

Comment: I appreciate your help, but it did not help me